# Start a second copy of the program with the same arguments

Tags: c#

What is the correct way for a application to restart another copy of itself with the same arguments?

My current method is to do the following

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start New Copy");
    Console.ReadLine();

    string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

    //Will not work if using vshost, uncomment the next line to fix that issue.
    //args[0] = Regex.Replace(args[0], "\\.vshost\\.exe$", ".exe");

    //Put quotes around arguments that contain spaces.
    for (int i = 1; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        if (args[i].Contains(' '))
            args[i] = String.Concat('"', args[i], '"');
    }

    //Combine the arguments in to one string
    string joinedArgs = string.Empty;
    if (args.Length > 1)
        joinedArgs = string.Join(" ", args, 1, args.Length - 1);

    //Start the new process
    Process.Start(args[0], joinedArgs);
}
```

However it seems like there is a lot of busy work in there. Ignoring the striping of the vshost, I still need to wrap arguments that have spaces with `"` and combine the array of arguments in to a single string.

Is there a better way to launch a new copy of the program (including the same arguments), perhaps a way just needing to pass in [Enviroment.CommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline) or takes a string array for the arguments?

Comment: Aww, a .NET fork bomb, how cute :)

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 There is a reason I put the `Console.ReadLine()` in :)

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/twistylittlepassagesallalike/archive/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-arguments-the-wrong-way.aspx about combining parsed command-line arguments back into a single string. Shorter version: it's more complicated than `'"'+arg+'"'`.

Comment: Trying to understand the use-case for this...  Hmm

Comment: @JMC I have a program that is a replacement shell for windows when people RDP in, however some users (administrators) need the full desktop + my replacement shell app, so what I do is: 1. I detect if the user is a admin, 2. Check to see if explorer is already running in the current session, 3. Launch Explorer and hide my replacement shell (as closing the shell logs off the current user.) 4. Launch a new copy of the replacement shell that will not logoff windows with termination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to quote command line arguments that contain spaces (and perhaps other characters, that I am not sure of). Perhaps something like this:

```
var commandLine = string.Join(" ", args.Select(s => s.Contains(' ') ? "\"" + s + "\"" : s));
var newProcess = Process.Start("yourapplication.exe", commandLine);
```

Additionally, rather than using

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

You could just accept them in your `Main` method instead:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var commandLine = string.Join(" ", args.Select(s => s.Contains(' ') ? "\"" + s + "\"" : s));
    var newProcess = Process.Start(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0], commandLine);
}
```

The vshost workaround you have right now seems fine, alternatively you could disable the whole vshost thing by unchecking "Enable Visual Studio hosting process" on the debug tab of your project. Some debugging features do get disabled when do you that. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242202%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a good explanation of that.

**EDIT**:

A better way to work around it would be to get the codebase to the entry point assembly:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var imagePath = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase;
    var commandLine = string.Join(" ", args.Select(s => s.Contains(' ') ? "\"" + s + "\"" : s));
    var newProcess = Process.Start(imagePath, commandLine);
}
```

That will work with or without the vshost enabled.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "Enable Visual Studio hosting process" option.  I like that a lot better than trying to hack around it in the code.

Comment: I know about un-checking the hosting process, that is why it is commented in my code, because I unchecked that process. But I didn't want people who just copied and pasted my code to wonder why it did not work.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Added one more alternative to avoiding the vshost problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this should work I guess.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern System.IntPtr GetCommandLine();
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  System.IntPtr ptr = GetCommandLine();
  string commandLine = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ptr); 
  string arguments = commandLine.Substring(commandLine.IndexOf("\"", 1) + 2);
  Console.WriteLine(arguments);
  Process.Start(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location, arguments);
}
```

Reference: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetCommandLine.html

Comment: That's the function I was thinking of but couldn't remember the name of.

Comment: That's basically a more complicated way of saying `Environment.CommandLine`, and it won't work because the `Process.Start` expects the file name and arguments as two separate parameters.

Comment: its not a complicated way its just the actual command line. btw why -ve vote??? updated the code to give you only the arguments. You can also remove the current executing exe path from the command line, instead of the substring expression I've used.

Comment: The downvote was because the code will not run as posted however the update fixed the problem. And it is a more convoluted way of doing the same thing. Go see what `Environment.CommandLine` returns it is the same thing as your pInvoke call.

Comment: yeah.. was just feeling lazy to put some extra effort into splitting it.

Answer (score -1):

would this suffice?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string commandLineArgs = args.Join(" ");
}
```

Comment: Nope, test it out using the command line arguments `This is "some args"` Your first run will be `args[0] = "This"; args[1] = "is"; args[2] = "some args"` but your seccond run will be `args[0] = "This"; args[1] = "is"; args[2] = "some"; args[3] = "args"`

Comment: Also you don't address how to start the process at all. Include that and deal with the extra arg you create and I will remove my -1.